# Get a JSON file with socket node js

Tags: json, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to receive a JSON file with socket from an android client. 
I have tried this :

```
 socket.on("EVT_ReceptionArtefactMessage", function (artefact) {
console.log(artefact.title) 
});
```

and this is the android code

```
private final static String JSON_PSEUDO = "creator";
private final static String JSON_TITLE = "title";
private final static String JSON_MESSAGE = "message";

public JSONObject toJSON() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_PSEUDO, this.pseudo);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_TITLE, this.title);
        object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_MESSAGE, this.message);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}


socket.emit("EVT_ReceptionArtefactMessage",artefact.toJSON());
```

but it is not working. can you please tell me what is the propre thing to do ?

Comment: Why is this not working? How are you emitting the message? Is your `JSON` really a `JSON string` or a `JavaScript Object` that references other objects?

Comment: i edited my question , you can check it

Comment: what u get if you just print artefact to console? "console.log(artefact)"

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(artefact))`.